# Can't replicate a DATE_FORMAT query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

So, i have this query in written out in a different version of my project.

```
    $result = $db->select("SELECT `nID`, `txNome`, `txEmail`
        FROM `".$this->tablename."`
        WHERE `at_state` != 'invalid'
        AND `dtCreated` < :weekAgo
        AND DATE_FORMAT(dtCreated, '%w') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%w')
        AND `remarketing_amigos_sent` = '1'
        AND `amigo` IS NULL
        AND `txEmail` NOT IN (
            SELECT `email`
            FROM `utils`.`unsubscribe`
            WHERE `email` = `".$this->tablename."`.`txEmail`
            AND (`idCampaign` = :campaign OR `idCampaign` = '*')
        );
    ", array(
        'campaign' => CoreHelper::getCampaignID(),
        'weekAgo' => $aWeekAgo
    ));
```

And i'm trying to convert it for Laravel's Query Builder, i can convert the whole thing except for that DATE_FORMAT bit... I have no idea how to convert that into Eloquent.

The Application should sent e-mails once a week to a list of people, that's why the DATE_FORMAT is there, to match the weekdays.
How can i convert this into Query Builder?

My current code looks like this

```
    $this->lead->where('at_state', '!=', 'invalid')
               ->where('dtCreated', '<', $aWeekAgo)
               ->where(???)
               ->where('remarketing_amigos_sent', '1')
               ->whereNull('amigo')
               ->whereNotIn('txEmail', function($q) {
                   $q->select('email')->from('utils.unsubscribe')->where('idCampaign', CoreHelper::getCampaignID());
               })->get();
```

Note that the $this->lead section is **intentionally different** because it refers to my **Eloquent Model**, whereas the original version was done using the DB **Facade**.

Comment: Can you show your code for what you have already started doing as well?

Comment: @RossWilson I've edited the original post with the new query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Laravel's whereRaw() function to accomplish some complex queries as:

```
->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(dtCreated, '%w') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%w')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
->where(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(dtCreated, '%w') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%w')"))
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#running-queries

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You may use this condition, Here I am showing an example, which I have implemented in my project.

```
$today  = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );

$presentStudents = StudentAttendance::where('status_id', 1)
->where( 'DATE_FORMAT(attendance_date,\'%Y-%m-%d\'', $today )
```

Comment: I could not get your answer to work without `raw`. This worked: `->where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(momentOfOfferUtc, '%Y-%m-%d')"), $momentOfOfferUtcParamConverted)`